# you will usually see cats dancing to the beautiful tunes sung by him meaning

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction, word-meaning, difference

> you will usually see cats dancing to the beautiful tunes sung by him

i want the meaning of this line but could not find yet i have know idea about this phrase meaning

Questin is you will usually see cats dancing to the beautiful tunes sung by him?

Comment: Presumably you have looked up the individual words so it is not clear why the whole thing does not make sense to you. Can you edit it to say what you think it might mean to help people see your problem?

Comment: Please also tell us what book you read this in.

Comment: this is bio of some person "A passionate technophile who also happens to be a Computer Science gratuate.you will usually see cats dancing to the beautiful tunes sung by him"

Comment: The expression has no idiomatic meaning. Since cats don't dance in real life, perhaps the man has created one or more computer animations of dancing cats?